# Jenkins pipeline failing github notification

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins pipeline that was working very good untill 2 days ago.
Now it fails on setting notification for github repo.
The code is

```
githubNotify account:orgPar, "myrepo": repoPar, sha: "12345ebaf", context: 'Core3 Linux Full Test', credentialsId: 'credentials',description: "TEST", status: "TEST0", targetUrl: "my url"
```

I get error

```
   an exception which occurred:
    in field _processor
    in field cause
    in field cause
    in field cause
    in field locals
    in field parent
    in field parent
    in field caller
    in field parent
    in field parent
    in field caller
    in field e
    in field program
    in field threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1296f24c
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:140)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:434)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:422)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:362)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please format the exception properly. It's hard to read as is.

Comment: Did you change something ? Upgrade a plugin or change configuration?

Comment: No nothing was changed.Ive updated plugin. Ive refreshed access tokens. Ive created new repo with new user and generated token for him and reconfigured project to use it. Ive restarted whole setup. Its really frustrating but nothing.

Comment: Ive basicaly implemented same set status notification in go. Ive deployed the package on each jenskins slave and run it as external command